# Set dropdown options from C# in jqgrid

Tags: c#, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am generating column model at server end using C# and passing jSON to the grid. Now I want one column to give a dropdown functionality. But it is not working out, this is what I have so far:

```
StringBuilder deptDetails = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Department dept in departmentList)
{
    deptDetails.Append(dept.DepartmentID);
    deptDetails.Append(":'");
    deptDetails.Append(":'" + dept.DepartmentName + "',");
    deptDetails.Append(',');
}
deptDetails.Length -= 1;

colModel[i] = new ColumnMod
{
    name = selectedItems[i].ToString(),
    index = selectedItems[i].ToString(),
    width = 100,
    editable = true,
    edittype = "select",
    align = "left",
    editoptions="{value:{" + deptDetails + "}}"
 };
```

Here is my columnmodel class:

```
public class ColumnMod
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string index { get; set; }
    //public Boolean key { get; set; }
    public Int32 width { get; set; }
    public Boolean editable { get; set; }
    public string edittype { get; set; }
    //public Boolean sortable { get; set; }
    public string align { get; set; }
    //public Boolean hidden { get; set; }
    public string editoptions { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is my JS code:

```
$grid.jqGrid({
    colNames: selectedItems,
    colModel: columnSelected,
    sortname: selectedValues[0],
    sortorder: "asc",
    editurl: 'url',
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    cellEdit: true,
    rowNum: 5000,
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 30,
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    gridview: true,
    pager: '#gridPager',
    viewrecords: true,
    recordtext: "Total Rows: {2}",
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "totalpages",
        records: "totalrecords",
        cell: "cell",
        id: selectedValues[0], //index of the column with the PK in it 
        userdata: "userdata",
        repeatitems: true
    },
    prmNames: {
        rows: "numRows",
        page: "page",
        sort: "sortField",
        order: "sortOrder"
    },
    datatype: function (postdata) {
        if (lastSortField != postdata.sortField || lastSortOrder != postdata.sortOrder)
         {   if (!$('#btnValidate').is(':disabled')) {
                lastSortField = postdata.sortField;
                lastSortOrder = postdata.sortOrder;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I get value in columnModel:

```
function getSelectedColumnsJSON(selectedValues) {
try {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "/getSelectedColumnsJSON",
        data: $.toJSON({
            selectedItems: selectedValues
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (data.d)
                columnSelected = data.d;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            ShowMessage(error.responseText);
        }
    });
}
catch (ex) {
    ShowMessage(ex.message);
}
```

}

I am getting the dropdown select in the column, but it is empty, I have tried to follow the format that is explained **[here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules)**..any help?

Comment: Can you post your javascript code and markup here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand correctly your problem because you don't posted *the JSON data* which you use to fill the grid. Do you post `DepartmentID` or `DepartmentName` values in the input data? Probably you need to use [formatter:'select'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#formatter_type_select) additionally and it will solve your existing problem?

I don't understand the full scenario which you need to implement, but It's typically better to use `dataUrl` instead of usage of `value` property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions). Probably the only case when you really have to use `value` property is the usage of `formatter:'select'`. Only if the data returned from the server contains ids instead of string data the option `dataUrl` can't be used.

Comment: I have made the edit to the post. I want to have this: <select> 
<option value=deptIDGoesHere> deptNameGoesHere </option> 
... 
</select>

Comment: @faizanjehangir: You don't unanswered on my main question. You wrote "I want one column to give a dropdown functionality" and "I am getting the dropdown select in the column, but it is empty". Do you need to have dropdown **during editing** only? Additionally you posted fragment of your code and not posted *how the data will be encoded* in the server response. Depend on encoding the data which you construct in `editoptions` property of `ColumnMod` can be wrong. **The type of `editoptions` property should be object and not a string.**